# Error to make string in Delphi

Tags: delphi

Hi I am trying to get all this content in a string variable which I then used to create a text file

The problem is that it always fails when you use this code:

```
html: = '

<title> test </ title>

<STYLE type=text/css>

body, a: link {
background-color: black;
color: red;
Courier New;
cursor: crosshair;
font-size: small;
}

input, table.outset, table.bord, table, textarea, select, fieldset, td, tr {
font: normal 10px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica,
sans-serif;
background-color: black;
color: red;
border: 1px solid # 00FF0red0;
border-color: red
}

a: link, a: visited, a: active {
color: red;
font: normal 10px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica,
sans-serif;
text-decoration: none;
}

</ style>

';
```

What I have to do to make it work ?

Comment: You have to enclose each line in `''` quotes and concatenate such enclosed strings together. For instance [`this way`](http://pastebin.com/PfKC9fc5).

Comment: By the way, there are multiple issues with your HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to properly concatenate the string, using the `+` string concatenation operator.

```
html: = '<title> test </ title>' + sLineBreak +
        '<STYLE type=text/css>' + sLineBreak + sLineBreak +
        'body, a: link {' + sLineBreak +
        'background-color: black;' + sLineBreak +
        'color: red;' + sLineBreak +
        'Courier New;' + sLineBreak +
        'cursor: crosshair;' + sLineBreak +
        'font-size: small;' + sLineBreak +
        '}';  // Keep going with the rest of your text
```

Or, simply use a `TStringList`:

```
var
  html: TStringList;
begin
  html := TStringList.Create;
  try
    html.Add('<title> test </ title>');
    html.Add('');
    html.Add('<STYLE type=text/css>');
    html.Add('body, a: link {');
    html.Add('background-color: black');
    html.Add('color: red;');
    html.Add('Courier New;');
    html.Add('cursor: crosshair;');
    html.Add('font-size: small;');
    html.Add('}';  // Keep going with the rest of your text

    html.SaveToFile('YourFileName.html');
  finally
    html.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: `#13#10` for a windows linebreak but you should be using `sLineBreak` instead of these magic constants. If you use `sLineBreak` then your code works on all platforms.

Comment: @David: Yes, I agree. Edited accordingly (and to fix missing closing parens).